# Onclick email back button to move back to Fragment page

Tags: android, email

- I am using implicit intent for sending email.I have posted the code
  below:

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
    if(items[position].equals("Make a Suggestion")) {

     Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

     emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "productdemo.admin@gmail.com");

     emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");

     emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Suggestion");

     emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

     startActivity(emailIntent);

 }
```

- using implicit intent it is opening gmail application with sender
  mail and subject in below screenshot:
- you can see the gmail back button placed before the compose text.If I
  click that back button it is moving to gmail inbox page shown like
  this:

[image]
[image]

- But I need to go back to my application **SettingsFragment** page.

Comment: Not possible. Gmail app has the same policy, as I'm doing for my apps. If user will press back button in navigation bar(bottom of screen), then I'm just popping stack(in most cases it is done automatically, if you have not overriden onBackPressed in Activity class).
But if user will press back button in toolbar (top of screen), then I'm moving user to HP of my app [or screen, that is on level - 1 to current one], as I'm assuming, that he would like to make some more operations/actions in my app

Comment: @MateuszPryczkowski Can you post your comment as an answer.I am willing to accept it

Comment: done and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Gmail app has the same policy, as I'm doing for my apps. If user will press back button in navigation bar(bottom of screen), then I'm just popping stack(in most cases it is done automatically, if you have not overriden onBackPressed in Activity class). But if user will press back button in toolbar (top of screen), then I'm moving user to HP of my app [or screen, that is on level - 1 to current one], as I'm assuming, that he would like to make some more operations/actions in my app